# Unassigned Reference to Inspector-Assigned Variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I keep getting this error:

`UnassignedReferenceException: The variable playerPhysics of PlayerMovement has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the playerPhysics variable of the PlayerMovement script in the inspector.`

but I've already assigned the rigidBody of the player object to the script in the inspector & it also functions when the game itself is running. All the script really does is add a basic force in a direction to a ball that is on a flat plane, and the force is applied even while this error keeps appearing. Can anyone help?

Some images of the screen:

[image: The inspector]

[image: The script]

Comment: In general you never want to use `new` for anything inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` or Unity built-in component types! Are you sure you're looking at the correct instance?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Instead, add the relevant code directly to your post.

Comment: Also: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Why not simply use `playerPhysics = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` once in `Start` so you don't nead to rely on that it is referenced via the Inspector at all ... ?

Comment: As @derHugo mentioned, avoid `new` when working with MonoBehavior descendents. Instead, add the `Rigidbody` in the inspector. In `Start()`, use `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` to get a reference to it.

Comment: @derHugo You beat me to it. :)

Comment: If for some reason you do want to add a new component runtime (that does not exist in the inspector before), there is the AddComponent<Rigidbody>() method. However in your case GetComponent() is really what you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

possibly 2 scripts in the Scene.
try:

```
    private void Start()
    {
        PlayerPhysics = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had another object assigned to the PlayerMovement script that was not supposed to move. Oops!